# Flask Application with ACL

Tags: flask, permissions, roles, acl, user-management

I wanted to create an application using Flask, for the ACL part I was using Flask Security but the package was quite old and deprecated. I looked into some other package Flask Perm that serves the same purpose but the last commit was 2 years ago. What package should I go with to implement Roles and Permissions in my flask app?

Comment: If you don't have many roles in your app, this may be overkill, but I recommend: https://pypi.org/project/openfga-sdk/. Disclaimer: I work on this product